# Lots of "Uncaught signal: 6" errors in Cloud Run

Tags: python-3.x, docker, google-cloud-platform, fastapi, google-cloud-run

I have a Python (3.x) webservice deployed in GCP. Everytime Cloud Run is shutting down instances, most noticeably after a big load spike, I get many logs like these `Uncaught signal: 6, pid=6, tid=6, fault_addr=0.` together with `[CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:6)` They are always signal 6.

The service is using FastAPI and Gunicorn running in a Docker with this start command

```
CMD gunicorn -w 2 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker -b 0.0.0.0:8080 app.__main__:app
```

The service is deployed using Terraform with 1 gig of ram, 2 cpu's and the timeout is set to 2 minutes

```
resource "google_cloud_run_service" <ressource-name> {
  name     = <name>
  location = <location>

  template {
    spec {
      service_account_name = <sa-email>
      timeout_seconds = 120
      containers {
        image = var.image
        env {
          name = "GCP_PROJECT"
          value = var.project
        }
        env {
          name = "BRANCH_NAME"
          value = var.branch
        }
        resources {
          limits = {
            cpu = "2000m"
            memory = "1Gi"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  autogenerate_revision_name = true
}
```

I have already tried tweaking the resources and timeout in Cloud Run, using the --timeout and --preload flag for gunicorn as that is what people always seem to recommend when googling the problem but all without success. I also dont exactly know why the workers are timing out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless you have enabled **CPU is always allocated**,  background threads and processes might stop receiving CPU time after all HTTP requests return. This means background threads and processes can fail, connections can timeout, etc. I cannot think of any benefits to running background workers with Cloud Run except when setting the **--cpu-no-throttling** flag. Cloud Run instances that are not processing requests, can be terminated.

Signal 6 means **abort** which terminates processes. This probably means your container is being terminated due to a lack of requests to process.

[Run more workloads on Cloud Run with new CPU allocation controls](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-run-gets-always-on-cpu-allocation)

[What if my application is doing background work outside of request processing?](https://github.com/ahmetb/cloud-run-faq/blob/master/README.md#what-if-my-application-is-doing-background-work-outside-of-request-processing)

Comment: Is there some kind of best practice on how I would run a python webservice?
In the google docs they also use guniorn although with slightly different arguments.
see: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/python

for now I copied their arguments (had to add the -k <worker class> for fastapi to work) to see if that'll work

Comment: @JeremySchiemann I refer to Ahmet's Google Cloud Run FAQ. https://github.com/ahmetb/cloud-run-faq Cloud Run is basically a simple HTTP Request/Response system. Most server setups beyond that are not necessary.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me alot. Using only one worker and setting the timeout to 0 fixed it for me already. But the FAQ will be bookmarked!

Answer (score 15):

Extending on the top answer which is correct, You are using **GUnicorn** which is a process manager that manages **Uvicorn** processes which runs the actual app.

When Cloudrun wants to shutdown the instance (due to lack of requests probably) it will send a **signal 6** to process 1. However, GUnicorn occupies this process as the manager and will not pass it to the Uvicorn workers for handling - thus you receive the **Unhandled signal 6**.

The simplest solution, is to run Uvicorn directly instead of through GUnicorn (possibly with a smaller instance) and allow the scaling part to be handled via Cloudrun.

```
CMD ["uvicorn", "app.__main__:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8080"]
```

Comment: This is an interesting/useful answer.

Comment: I struggled with this error notifications for some time myself until diving into it, when I tested adding signal handlers to the fastapi / uvicorn app it simply did nothing - until i figured out that it was the GUnicorn hogging the process 1 and not forwarding this.

Essentially we use GUnicorn for scaling purposes - handling multiple requests simultaneously by the GUnicorn raising Uvicorn processes. Since we are in a CloudRun environment and can set the in-flight requests to as many as we like we can let Uvicorn handle his request, and get the scaling from Cloudrun.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Although i already fixed my problem with the other answer, I'm sure this is useful information to float around the internet.

Comment: I am getting error like `/opt/startup/startup.sh: 26: CMD: not found`

Comment: @Sathiamoorthy Are you working through docker and verified that you install `uvicorn` before running the CMD line ?

Comment: Is there any disadvantage using gunicorn over uvicorn? Specially performance-wise since gunicorn is written in python

Answer (score 1):

This error happens when a background process is aborted. There are some advantages of running background threads on cloud just like for other applications. Luckily, you can still use them on Cloud Run without processes getting aborted. To do so, when deploying, chose the option "CPU always allocated" instead of "CPU only allocated during request processing"

For more details, check https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/cpu-allocation