# Getting Uncaught signal: 6, pid=1, tid=43, fault_addr=0." error for GCP cloud run

Tags: google-cloud-run

Getting **Uncaught signal: 6, pid=1, tid=43, fault_addr=0." error** for GCP cloud run

I am using java application and hosting in GCP cloud run service. We got this error Getting Uncaught signal: 6, pid=1, tid=43, fault_addr=0." i log. My application api failing 502 bad gateway.

I have set cpu_allocation         = "--no-cpu-throttling" for cloud run and increased memory from 512 MIB to 2 GiB. but no luck

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lots of "Uncaught signal: 6" errors in Cloud Run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70272414/lots-of-uncaught-signal-6-errors-in-cloud-run)